# Scaleout handlers in Nservicebus

Tags: parallel-processing, nservicebus

I have a WCF service which sends out commands to process some work at the handlers. Since I am doing this as a POC I have only one machine for handler and one for WCF. So my question is how can I make the Handler Executable run like 4 instances on the same machine(Like 4 threads at the same time).

To be more clear I want to run 4 parallel worker handlers on the same machine. Is there a setting while installing service or in configuration I can set this setting.

Answer (score 3):

In v4 of NServiceBus you can configure the `MaximumConcurrencyLevel`, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/msmqtransportconfig#nservicebus-v4-changes-to-msmqtransportconfig